# Checking if a modified element of an array is a member in the same array

Tags: arrays, factor-lang

I have an array:

```
{ "abc" "def" "cba" "fed" "junk" }
```

I want to check if each item in the array has its reversed version as a member in the same array.

In Python, I would express this as:

```python
>>> array = ["abc", "def", "cba", "fed", "junk"]
>>> [item for item in array if item[::-1] in array] # [::-1] reverses a string
['abc', 'def', 'cba', 'fed']
```

Or even:

```
>>> list(filter(lambda x: x[::-1] in array, array))
['abc', 'def', 'cba', 'fed']
```

I've tried:

```
IN: scratchpad dup [ dup reverse swap member? ] filter

--- Data stack:
{ "abc" "def" "cba" "fed" "junk" }
{  }
```

Nope, the quotation fails for each item.

I'm sure there's an obvious answer, or a combinator and quotation which does this efficiently. What is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you need a closure. The quotation that runs on each element needs to look at a value other than the element itself. A convenient syntax for writing closures is implemented using [fried quotations](http://docs.factorcode.org/content/article-fry.html).

E.g:

```
{ "abc" "def" "cba" "fed" "junk" } dup '[ reverse _ in? ] map
```

You bind the value from the stack at the "outside" to the `_` spot on the "inside". You can construct and run an equivalent closure with `with` or using `curry` which is a more low-level word:

```
{ "abc" "def" "cba" "fed" "junk" } dup [ reverse swap in? ] with map
```

Then you add `all?` to check that all values satisfies the predicate:

```
{ "abc" "def" "cba" "fed" "junk" } dup '[ reverse _ in? ] all?
```

`USE: sets` to load the `in?` word.

Comment: Aha! Thanks so much!

Comment: So `in?` is for `set`s and `member?` is for `seq`uences. An `{ array }` is a sequence, right? So is there a reason to use `in?` over `member?`?

Comment: `in?` is a few characters shorter than `member?`. For sequences, they do the same thing. The reason there are two variants is likely legacy.

Comment: That makes sense. [mrjbq7 said *"I kind of want all words to be generic."*](https://github.com/factor/factor/issues/1586#issuecomment-201096181), so maybe they'll be synonymised in the future, which would be so choice.